# Java ImageIO Read and Write compressed Tiff files with CIE lab colorspace

Tags: image-processing, tiff, javax.imageio, cielab

I actually try to read and write compressed tif-files with CIE Lab colorspace.

Unfortunally if I try to just read and after this write the tif back to the HDD the color is different from the soure tif.

Is the ImageIO lib able to read and write compressed tif files with CIE lab color space?

If it is possible I fear that something is wrong with the code. In the singleTiffs list are at least one tiff-ImageInputStream which is created in this way: 
ImageIO.createImageInputStream(testTiff)

Would be great if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

```
// Get iterator for input images
    Iterator<ImageInputStream> iterator = singleTiffs.iterator();

    // Get tif writer and set output to file
    Iterator writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(newMultiPageTIFF);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    // Write each image out to the new file
    boolean firstImage = true;
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {

        ImageInputStream iis = iterator.next();

        // Get a reader for the stream
        Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
        reader.setInput(iis);


        // Read the stream metadata
        // IIOMetadata streamMetadata = reader.getStreamMetadata();

        // Read the image metadata - we are assuming there is only one image
        // in the tiff
        IIOMetadata imageMetadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

        // Set up the writeParam
        TIFFImageWriteParam tiffWriteParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.US);
        tiffWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_COPY_FROM_METADATA);

        BufferedImage bi = reader.read(0, null);
        IIOImage image = new IIOImage(bi, null, imageMetadata);
        if(firstImage == false)
            writer.writeInsert(-1, image, tiffWriteParam);
        else
        {
            writer.write(null, image, tiffWriteParam);
            firstImage = false;
        }

        // Done writing all images for this image
        reader.dispose();
    }

    // End writing of all files
    writer.dispose();
```

Comment: please ask only one question per post

Comment: Sorry, I thought both are related to each other, because if the answer of question 1 is "no" question 2 becomes obsolete. Next time I will create several posts for several questions.

Comment: Ok then I'm sorry, I reviewed your question without reading it too thoroughly. I guess you can easily rephrase the "First Question" - "Second Question" wording, the community doesn't like to see those phrases ;)